# Why does Fabric usually output an extra empty line?

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

In Fabric deployments, there is often an extra empty response line output.

ie, after running

```
run('pwd')
```

Fabric will return

```
[mydomain] out: /mydir
[mydomain] out:
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to an old issue that the maintainer marked as fixed.

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/219